Would it be legal to credit an original song to “traditional”?
Suppose I write a song which, as far as I know, is original and not derived from any other work. I record it and credit the composition to “traditional” rather than myself.
Assume I never claim royalties or authorship, but it becomes known to the public that I composed it. Would there be any legal consequences?

Possibly a truth in advertising violation, if there is commerce involved.

If you achieve any financial benefit from this lie, I suppose it could be considered fraud. But it's hard to see how you could benefit from it.

@Barmar You could create a record with faked genuine medieval dance music, when medieval dance music becomes fashionable:-)

A copyright owner can use a pseudonym
For example, who can forget the masterpiece of dystopia, 1984, written by Eric Arthur Blair.
If you want to attribute your work to “traditional”, you are free to do so. Providing you can prove you wrote it, you are also free to enforce your copyright against anyone who violates it. Equity will probably not allow you to recover damages from anyone who innocently misused it given that you indicated it was public domain when it wasn’t, but you could certainly stop them using it in the future.
